# Mobile menu not displaying in landscape

Tags: wordpress, drop-down-menu, navigation

I'm trying to get the mobile menu to display in landscape mode, however so far have been unsuccessful in finding out how to achieve this. It only seems to display when the height is greater than the width.

Works fine in portrait, yet displays normal menu in landscape.

I have no code to share or such, as the issue is so loosely defined from my prospective.

http://client.n8geeks.com

The menu code used...

```
    <nav id="site-navigation" class="main-navigation" role="navigation">
    <a href="/"><img class="logo-responsive" src="/images/logo-responsive.png"></a>
        <h3 class="menu-toggle"><?php _e( '', 'twentytwelve' ); ?><div class="menu-btn"><span class="icn-bar"></span><span class="icn-bar"></span><span class="icn-bar"></span></div></h3>
        <a class="assistive-text" href="#content" title="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Skip to content', 'twentytwelve' ); ?>"><?php _e( 'Skip to content', 'twentytwelve' ); ?></a>
        <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'primary', 'menu_class' => 'nav-menu' ) ); ?>
    </nav><!-- #site-navigation -->
```

Comment: The header.php (or whatever file the menu is in) code would be helpful.

Comment: Can we see the css as well, specifically for the class `logo-responsive`